# Rails collection_check_boxes not returnig selected values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Im new on Rails and I feel a kind of stuck right now, I need to develop an app where you associate Congresses and Users, has_and_belong_to_many, the point is that I have this on my view:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :administrators_id %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :administrators_id, @users,'id','user_id',{multiple: true, class: 'checkbox inline'} %>
```

this is on my controllers:

```
def new
  @congress = Congress.new
  @users = User.all
end

# GET /congresses/1/edit
def edit
  @users = User.all
end

# POST /congresses
# POST /congresses.json
def create

  @congress = Congress.new(congress_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @congress.save
      format.html { redirect_to @congress, notice: 'Congress was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @congress }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @congress.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /congresses/1
# PATCH/PUT /congresses/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @congress.update(congress_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @congress, notice: 'Congress was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @congress }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @congress.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But I dont get it to work, checked vales adoes not store at all.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :adminstrations
  has_many :congresses, through: :adminstrations
end

class Congress < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :adminstrations
  has_many :adminstrators, through: :adminstrations, 
                           source: :user
end

class Administration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :congress
end
```

See [Why You Don’t Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/). You can call the join model whatever you want. But in 99% of cases you'll want to have it sooner or later.

To assign associations from an array (created by a select or checkboxes) you need to use the `_ids` setter. Not `_id`. `_id` is singular and will only work if the relation is one to one.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :administrators_ids %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :administrators_ids, @users, :id, :email, {multiple: true, class: 'checkbox inline'} %>
</div>
```

The two methods should be the value and the label method to be used on the user instance when generating the option tags. Use symbols here instead of strings for readability.

Make sure you are whitelisting the correct param as well:

```
def congress_params
  params.require(:congress)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, :administrators_ids)
end
```

Comment: Really Thanks for your help!!

Im trying to change to the has_many: Through structure but now im getting an SQL Error:

`SQLException: no such column: administrations.user_id: SELECT "users".id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "administrations" ON "users"."id" = "administrations"."user_id" WHERE "administrations"."congress_id" = ?`

I think this is because the db migration is creating administrations table with one colum named 'administrator_id' instead of using 'user_id'

can you please give me any recommendation ??

Comment: Rollback the migration and run: `rails g model administration user:belongs_to congress:belong_to --force` this will give you a correct migration.

Comment: Or create a new migration with `rails g migration add_user_id_to_administrations user:belongs_to`